# Spring Cloud Data Flow - rabbitmq source sink example

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

i am looking at the documentation for spring Cloud Data flow.

https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/recipes/rabbitmq/rabbit-source-sink/

This example that uses RabbitMQ as source and sink is using Spring Cloud Streams framework - which is fine. But it doesn't show how these 3 apps - source, sink and processor can be deployed to Spring Cloud Data Flow (SCDF), it simply just runs three jars locally and they talk to each other via RabbitMQ Queues. 
I am not sure how this shows the use of SCDF in this case. There's no involvement of SCDF in this case. A proper example that shows how to deploy this jars as apps inside the SCDF needs to be provided. am i missing anything in this case?. i am hoping somebody else has tried them and can share their feedback about my concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation [here](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/stream-developer-guides/streams/data-flow-stream/) covers the SCDF part of how to manage those source, processor and sink applications.